# Inserir dados de uma tabela em outra

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, tabela-html

Galera, eu estou quebrando a cabeça com esse problema já tem um tempo e queria a ajuda de vocês. Eu tenho um código que insere dados na tabela `venda`:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        $venda = $_POST['num_venda'];
        $data = $_POST['data_venda'];
        $placa = $_POST['placa'];
        $km = $_POST['km'];
        $produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
        $servicos = $_POST['servicos'];

        include ('banco.php');


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO venda(id_venda, num_venda, data_venda, placa, km, produtos, servicos)
        values(
            NULL,
            '{$venda}',
            '{$data}',
            '{$placa}',
            '{$km}',
            '{$produtos}',
            '{$servicos}'

                        )
        ");



        header("location:listadevendas.php");


    }





    ?>
```

E eu tenho outras tabelas `venda_produto(id, id_venda, produtos)` e `venda_servico(id, id_venda, servicos)`. Eu queria inserir os dados da tabela `venda` nelas, que seriam (id_venda e produtos ou servicos). Li em alguns lugares para usar triggers mais não consegui e outros pra usar inner join mas também não consegui. Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou utilizar o insert..select?

```
INSERT INTO venda_produto (id, id_venda, produtos)
  SELECT venda.id, venda.id_venda, venda.produtos
  FROM venda;
```

Comment: eu tentei assim mas tbm nao deu certo , sera que nao tem outro jeito ?

Comment: "não deu certo" é meio vago. Precisa ver onde está errando, em vez de ficar mudando o jeito até dar sorte.

Comment: opa , fiz algumas ediçoes aki e deu certinho , muito obrigado vc me tiro uma dor de cabeça enorme ;)

Comment: @MatheusGoes qual erro ocorreu na execução? você editou corretamente as tabelas/colunas da query?

Comment: disponha fera! :)

Answer (score 3):

Sua pergunta não ficou clara o suficiente, mas vamos lá. Faça uma tabela relacionada da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No modelo acima, será criado uma linha nas tabelas venda, venda_produto e venda_servico sempre que algo for cadastrado. Esse modelo foi feito seguindo suas instruções. Se os produtos e serviços já estão pre-definidos no sistema, seria interessante um outro modelo que cadastrasse uma nova linha apenas na tabela venda e fizesse a relação dela com os produtos pre-definidos.

Código SQL pra gerar essas tabelas (altere conforme suas necessidades):

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 12/01/15 15:16:18
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `venda_produto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `venda_produto` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `produtos` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = MyISAM;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `venda_servico`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `venda_servico` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `servicos` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = MyISAM;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `venda`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `venda` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `placa` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `km` INT NOT NULL,
  `produtos` INT NULL,
  `servicos` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_venda_venda_produto_idx` (`produtos` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_venda_venda_servico1_idx` (`servicos` ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Faça conexão com o banco de dados usando MySQLi (a função MySQL é obsoleta)

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8') or die(mysqli_connect_error($link));
```

Antes de montar o INSERT, faça escape em todos os dados passados por $_POST para dificultar ataques de SQL Injection.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $key    = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $key);
    $value  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);
    $data[$key] = $value;
}
```

Faça INSERT na tabela venda e pegue o ID gerado

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `venda`(`numero`, `data`, `placa`, `km`, `produtos`, `servicos`)
    VALUES ('" . $data['num_venda'] . "', '" . $data['data_venda'] . "', '" . $data['placa'] . "', '" . $data['km'] . "');";

mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

//Pega o ID

$insertID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Faça INSERT nas tabelas de venda_produto e venda_servico e UPDATE na tabela de venda com o ID para as outras tabelas.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `venda_produto`(`id`, `produtos`) VALUES (" . $insertID . ", '" . $data['produtos'] . "'); INSERT INTO `venda_servico`(`servicos`) VALUES (" . $insertID . ", '" . $data['servicos'] . "'); UPDATE `venda` SET `produtos`=[" . $insertID . "],`servicos`=[" . $insertID . "] WHERE id = " . $insertID . ";";

mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

É isso.

Comment: +1 pela ênfase no MySQLi. MySQL não existe mais mo PHP 7 e desde o PHP 5.5+ estava deprecada.